# How to make an image correspond to each object in a NSMutableArray - xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Hi there I am trying to make a simple tableview directory with an image, a label and some info. 
I am using a NSMutableArray with objects to establish teacher names and now I would like to add an image in the cell that corresponds to the label.

I am looking for any suggestions. I have not found any up-to-date tutorials.

Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit
```

class DirectoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var backButton2: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var directoryTableView: UITableView!
```

// @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: NSLayoutConstraint!

```
//let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

var directoryObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

// var names = ["Teacher 1", "Teacher 2", "Teacher 3"]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 1")
    self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 2")
    self.directoryObjects.addObject("Teacher 3")

    self.directoryTableView.reloadData()


    directoryTableView.delegate = self
    directoryTableView.dataSource = self
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()



}




//Mark - tableview


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return directoryObjects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let directoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("directoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DirectoryTableViewCell

   directoryCell.nameLabel.text = self.directoryObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String


   // directoryCell.directoryLabel.text = names[indexPath.row]

    return directoryCell

}




@IBAction func backButton2Tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a struct

```
struct Object {
var teacherString: String!
var image: UIImage!
}
```

Then your array is

```
var theArray = [
Object(teacherString: "Teacher 1", image: UIImage(name: "yourImage")),
Object(teacherString: "Teacher 2", image: UIImage(name: "yourImage")),
Object(teacherString: "Teacher 3", image: UIImage(name: "yourImage"))]
```

Sorry if some of my code is bad. I wrote this in notepad on windows.

Comment: where would I add this code? and will I have to alter the rest of the code?

Comment: Add the struct above your class. You can add, change and remove the vars in the struct. Put the array where you have your string array right now.